# KSH return value is not integer

Tags: shell, ksh

I have a script that does a query (count) on a database, but the result is not an integer I have tried to change this with let but with out any luck

```
SQL="SELECT COUNT(*), INTRUDER FROM intruders WHERE UUR BETWEEN '${START}' and '${EINDE}' GROUP BY INTRUDER;"
```

The actual mysql command

```
RESULT=$(mysql -u ${MYSQLUSER} -p${MYSQLPWD} -h ${SERVER} ${DATABASE} -BsNe "${SQL}")
```

The loop that calculates

```
for RECORD in ${RESULT}
  do
    let TOTAL=$(echo ${RECORD} | awk '{print $1}')
    if [[ ${TOTAL} -ge ${MAXTRY} ]]; then
    ## Do something ....
    echo ${RECORD} | awk '{print $2}'
  fi
done
```

The error:
./script.sh[42]: let: TOTAL=3
4
4
4: arithmetic syntax error

Comment: What is the contents of RECORD before you get that shell script value?

Comment: Different problems here, you should choose another approach (beneath). When filling the RESULT var you should put the right site in double quotes to get all lines. This won't fix everything, the for loop considers both spaces and newlines as field separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can you use to awk to extract the integer 
the

```
`RESULT=$(mysql -u ${MYSQLUSER} -p${MYSQLPWD} -h ${SERVER} ${DATABASE} -BsNe "${SQL}")`
```

can be written as

```
`RESULT=$(mysql -u ${MYSQLUSER} -p${MYSQLPWD} -h ${SERVER} ${DATABASE} -BsNe "${SQL}"| awk "print $1")`
```

see if this solves your issue 
I have written above statement assuming you are suppressing the header of the result given by the query

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the output of the sql and loop through the results.
I added grep -v INTRUDER, I do not know if you have header records in your output.

```
TOTAL=0
mysql -u ${MYSQLUSER} -p${MYSQLPWD} -h ${SERVER} ${DATABASE} -BsNe "${SQL}" | 
   grep -v INTRUDER | while read intrudercount intrudername; do
      echo "Counting [${intrudername}]: ${intrudercount}"
      if [ ${intrudercount} -gt ${MAXTRY} ]; then
         echo "${intrudername} was very bad."
      fi
      (( TOTAL = TOTAL + ${intrudercount} ))
      echo "Subtotal until now: ${TOTAL}"
   done
```